# Archive pages have smaller font then the rest of my website

Tags: css, archives

I have my awesome [wordpress website here](http://thestuffedpepper.ca/wp/) that I have been working on for weeks now and all is great with it except for one thing! For some reason when you try to look at the [archives pages](http://thestuffedpepper.ca/wp/2012/03) the whole page's font gets smaller. I mean, any navigation link, text link, paragraphs, titles, etc.

I've checked my CSS and files but I can't seem to find out what is different with just that one page. I've used firebug to find out maybe the scripting is off in a section but I've had no luck finding anything different. I've tried to copy over from the twentyeleven archive.php page so I'd basically start as new as I could and then add in my extras but that didn't seem to work either.

Had anyone come across this issue before or has advice as to what might be happening?

I appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying a font size of 12px to any objects with the class `.date`, but, this class is being applied to the body element because it's a date archive.

So make your `.date` rule more specific.

Protip: Using a non-IE browser, press f12 to bring up the dev tools and inspect the elements

Comment: Thanks guys! It's difficult to keep track of all the CSS for a wordpress website!

Answer (score 5):

You're applying 12px font size to `.date` on line 260 of `style.css`. `.date`, along with `.archive` and `single-author` are being applied by `body_class()` (I presume) to the body of your post, thus changing the font size. For a full list of classes which `body_class()` can/does use, see [the codex page for `body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class).

Comment: Thanks guys! It's difficult to keep track of all the CSS for a wordpress website!